# Fastest way to screen-shot part of screen in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot, snipping

I have Windows 10 Pro. I'm a science teacher and a frequent user of the in-built snipping tool in Windows 10 Pro. I often create screen-shots of small parts of my screen to make "how-to" documents for my students. The "current-window-screen-shot" feature includes too much information. I'm only interested in the tiny portions of GeoGebra-calculations.

Currently I do as follows:

1. Windows button + S
2. Type `snipping tool` then press Enter. The application opens (or use your own custom hotkey-combination to open this app)
3. Choose New then select portion of the screen
4. Press Ctrl+C
5. Open a Word document
6. Press Ctrl+V

Since everything is done from the keyboard this procedure is pretty fast. But in OS-X it's only a 3-step procedure:

1. Cmd+Ctrl+Shift+4 then select portion of the screen
2. Open Word document
3. Cmd+V

Without buying a Mac (we only have PCs at work), what is the fastest possible way to take a screen shot of select a portion of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open Snipping Tool
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>
   (This starts a Rectangular snip -- select a portion of the screen)
3. Save the file.

You can pin Snipping Tool to the Windows Taskbar if you use it frequently and assign a keyboard shortcut such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

(or)

Maybe you can use a script like this:

[How to Automatically Take a Screenshot and Open it in a Editor?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/automatically-take-screenshot-open-in-editor/)

[How to Start Snipping Tool in Capture Mode by Default?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/start-snipping-tool-capture-mode-default/)

Comment: Pretty fast! And I didn't  know the clip automatically was stored in the clipboard! --> reduced number of seperate actions down to 4 
(Open->"new"-> clip! -> paste wherever you would like!) ! Almost as good as the inbuilt OS X tool!
Is it possible to reduce it by one more step? a hotkey directly to the rectangular clip?
By some reason, when I use an hotkey to open the snipping tool as you suggested, it takes up to 1 second before the app actually opens..?

Comment: Yes. Pls check the updated answer.

Comment: Even though one would have to wait for a second or so for the snip mode to initiate, the solution you provided saves me tons of (=about 2) seconds!:D Lets say I wasted 2 seconds on my previous solution 10 times during one day (20 seconds a day) --> around 180 workdays at office (3600 seconds=1 hour) --> 24 years at work = 1 day lost spending time waiting for the snipping tool to get going. Quite satisfying, thank you:)

Comment: Nice to hear. You're very welcome Eirik

Answer (score 1):

This process is as quick as your OSX example on Windows 10 since build 17661:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to open up the snipping tool and select the area of your screen that you want to capture
2. Open word doc
3. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>

Additionally you can also select the notification that pops up after step 1, which opens your capture in the snipping tool window, allowing you to save the screenshot to a file and/or make adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign any shortcut to run snipping tool:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/assign-a-shortcut-key-to-the-snipping-tool-in-windows-vista/

Comment: Assigned snipping tool to ctrl+alt+s which works pretty good, reducing number of seperate actions by 1. But still the OS X - way of things is more efficient... :/

Answer (score 0):

Use gyazo!
https://gyazo.com/

I love it, and use it alot!
Set it up and you're ready to go:

1. Download the program (big button on homepage, can't be missed).
2. Install it
3. Put it somewhere where you can click it fast, like the bar at the bottom of your screen (forgot the name)
4. Click it for an image (drag an area on the screen to capture, and collect it from the url that will popup), click the also downloaded program (search for gyazo gif) to capture gifs

It also allows you to capture gifs

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Since the OP is specifically interested in the *number of steps* involved, consider improving your post by providing step-by-step instructions on how to take a screen shot of a portion of the screen with this tool.  Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

A snip can be taken with a single click.

1. On the desktop, right click and select New...Shortcut.
2. Paste this in the location: snippingtool /clip
3. Click next, and give the shortcut a name, maybe QuickSnip
4. Click Finish. Drag your shortcut to the taskbar.

Now you just need to click on this and select the area to copy.

I much prefer this to the other answers. Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way I do this is by using a small tool named Fastone Screen Capture. It's a freeware and very easy to use. I used two or three such programs and it seems the fastest to me.

- [The download page](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm).
- [A simple tutorial of how to use it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIf8r.jpg)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.